# How to disable automatically checked button in Dynamics AX form?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

When I open my form the Edit button is "clicked" automaticaly. 
The DefaultButton property of Edit Buitton is set to 'No'.

What should I do for Edit button not to be clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the menu item that is used to open your form, set the OpenMode property to "View". This will cause the form to open in view mode.